# Intersection and complement proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove that if $A \cap B = A \cap C$ then $A \cap \overline{B} = A \cap \overline{C}$.

I've tried several manipulations, but I can't get to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: the first equality is equivalent to the statement "for every $x \in A$ we have $x \in B \iff x \in C$" and the second equality is equivalent to an analogous statement.

More explanation: Let's assume that $A \cap B = A \cap C$.  This means that for all $x$, the equivalence $x \in A \cap B \iff x \in A \cap C$ holds. In particular, this equivalence holds for all $x \in A$.  If we assume that $x$ is in $A$, then the intersections with $A$ do not do anything and we have the equivalence $x \in B \iff x \in C$.  This means that the equivalence $x \notin B \iff x \notin C$ also holds for all $x \in A$, and it's starting to resemble the second equality now...

Comment: So, $ \forall x \in A, x \in B \wedge x \in C$ is my first equality and 
$ \forall x \in A, x \in \neg B \wedge x \in \neg C$ is my second equality. Right ?

Comment: @Francis No, those statements say that $A \subset (B \cap C)$ and $A \subset (\bar{B} \cap \bar{C})$ respectively.  Roughly speaking, equality of sets corresponds to $\iff$, not $\land$.

Comment: The quoted sentence in my answer means that for every $x \in A$, the statement "$x \in B \iff x \in C$" is true.  That is, if we restrict our attention to members of $A$, then membership in $B$ is equivalent to membership in $C$.

Comment: Ok, I'm so lost, we haven't seen many ways to make a proof with equality and intersection/complement of. Could you provide me more information, please ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, dtldarek just gave an "algebraic" proof, so I'll try to explain the "logical" proof.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Well done both of you, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Another interpretation:

\begin{align}
A \cap B &= A \cap C  & \text{apply complement}\\
\overline{A \cap B} &= \overline{A \cap C} & \text{De Morgan's law} \\
\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} &= \overline{A} \cup \overline{C} & \text{apply } A\cap\bullet\\
A\cap \left(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}\right) &= A \cap \left(\overline{A} \cup \overline{C}\right) & \text{expand}\\
A \cap \overline{B} &= A \cap \overline{C}
\end{align}

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: @FrancisLacoste Trevor's answer, even if it contains less details, is _much nicer_. Please, try to understand it, as it could help you build intuitions about sets, while my few transformations provide nothing more that a formal proof.